# Multi-user app and Parse push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm working on a multi-user Android app, and I'm trying to implement Parse Push Notifications, I've never used them before, so i'm really confused about what's the aproach for handling multiple user. I don't want a user receiving another user's notifications.

Right now i'm getting the deviceToken:

```
(String) ParseInstallation parse = 
              ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
```

First, i thought that I should generate (if possible) a new "device token" when a different user logs in, and send it to my API. Or maybe have multiple tokens on the same installation. But, now i'm seeing on the parse documentation that I can associate a device with a user:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Maybe that's the way to go. But still i'm not sure. So I'm just asking for some guidance if possible. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: That is the correct way to go I would say. If you define the  push functionality in cloud code, you can make it target exactly installations matching the user(s) you want.

Comment: @ILovemyPoncho  i m doing same want to send notification to user while i m passing usernames in query but failed to recieve notification in device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303082/failed-to-recieve-notification-sending-on-button-click-using-parse-com-android